# How to change the background image IBM mobile anywhere app splash screen

Tags: maximo-anywhere

How to change the background image(black to white) in IBM mobile anywhere app splash screen, I have changed in this folder ipad\native\Resources, but it is not changing after redeploying the app, please help me  solve the issue.

Comment: Be more precise in your question. What are you talking about?

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_application_resources.html?lang=en

Comment: yes i have tried this link

Comment: I want to change splash screen image in IBM Mobile anywhere., in above mentioned floder i have changed, but that is not working, have u got my point., can u help me to solve